# GetBlockBlobReference is not working with absolute file path

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I have stored my file in azure storage and later on trying to read that file using below code. But it is giving an error 404 not found when I am giving the full file path like this 
"https://appsdemostore.blob.core.windows.net/content/82b159f4-6730-432d-b061-05cf0cdfa16d.txt". But when I am giving filepath as this "82b159f4-6730-432d-b061-05cf0cdfa16d.txt" it is working.I am facing this issue after upgrading the library.Is there any way to work the code with full fule path. Because in my database they are stored as full file path.

```
  CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filePath);

                return blockBlob.DownloadText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have storage credentials (account name/key), you could do the following:

```
        var credentials = new StorageCredentials("account-name", "account-key");
        var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(filePath), credentials);
        blob.DownloadText();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give the file name not the whole path.

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("82b159f4-6730-
                                           432d-b061-05cf0cdfa16d.txt");

            return blockBlob.DownloadText();
```

Comment: that will work I know but previously my code is working with absolute uri after upgrade it stopped working

Comment: Can you tell which version of storage client library you used before and after?